# Why is this object not being updated?

Tags: c#

In C#, if I have an object variable in a class, and a second class has an object variable that is set to the same object, how can both object variables be updated when the second class has the object variable changed?

Here is some code as an example:

```
public class Class1
{
    public object obj { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public object obj { get; set; }
}

private void SetObject()
{
    var class1 = new Class1();
    class1.obj = "test";

    var class2 = new Class2();
    class2.obj = class1.obj;

    class2.obj = "test2";
}
```

In the above code, when changing the `class2.obj`, the `class1.obj` stays the same. How is it possible for `class1.obj` to have the same value as `class2.obj` when any value is set to the `class2.obj`?

Comment: Did you try to set to a real object instead of a string object?

Comment: I would like the code to work with any type of object, where the object can have any value. I have used a string as an example.

Comment: Is this for learning purposes, or to achieve a particular goal? Because the short answer is it's not really possible

Comment: Can you please clarify *why* you expect `class1.obj` to change?

Comment: Ops, I didn't pay attention to what you were doing, I wrote an answer.

Comment: There are a number of blog posts apparently intended to frustrate learners. They start off with "boxing" and "stack" and "heap." All important but also the most confusing way possible to start. I might even just write my own blog post.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I added a [blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/29/dot-net-reference-types-for-absolute-beginners.html) that hopefully explains and demonstrates more clearly. Please don't be offended because it says "for absolute beginners." I don't know what your background/experience is, but I like to write from that perspective.

---

`class2.obj` isn't a value. It's a reference to an object. Before you call `class2.obj = "test2"`, `class2.obj` contains a reference to the string "test".

Then you're changing it to reference a different object - the string "test2".
`class1.obj` still points to the same object it did, which is a different object, the string "test."

If they were both pointing to the same object and you changed a property of that object you'd see the change reflected in both places, because then there would be two variables each referencing the same object.

This clicks once you get it, but I think an example is required to do it justice.

Suppose we have this class:

```
public class ThingWithValue
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And we create a few instances of it:

```
var thing1 = new ThingWithValue { Value = "A" };
var thing2 = new ThingWithValue { Value = "B" };
```

This creates a new variable pointing to the same object as `thing1`. There are two variables but only one object:

```
var thing3 = thing1;
```

So if I set a property on `thing3` then I'm also setting it on `thing1` because they're both the same object.

```
thing3.Value = "C";
```

But if I do this:

```
thing1 = null;
```

then the only thing I'm changing is the variable - it no longer points to that object. I'm not changing that object. It still exists. `thing3` wouldn't become `null`. It's still pointing to that same object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trowing the value from `class2.obj` away when doing

```
class2.obj = "test2";
```

Also, you could change it if `class1.obj` were an object and you change a **property** of it either on `class1.obj` or `class2.obj`. Not reassigning another object.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case you are indirectly doing the operation with string, the class object is not being mapped or assigned. Hence it is similar o the following:

```
string s1 = "abc";
string s2 = s1;
s2 = "123";
// this wont change the value of s1;
```

By assigning a string literal to a String variable, You are actually instantiate a new string object and assigned to the existing one:

What you are actually expected is that:

```
var class1Object1 = new Class1();
class1Object1.obj = "test";
var class1Object2 = new Class1();
class1Object2 = class1Object1;
class1Object2.obj = "test2";
```

Here you are creating two different instances of the class and assign one to another. so that changes in one object will reflect in the other too. but this is not possible in the case of strings since they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

It won't update the other variable because you're actually modifying the *pointer*, rather than the object.

For example, after running this

```
class1.obj = "test";
```

We can imagine the memory layout as follows:

```
Mem Address  Name        Value
0x0001       Class1.obj  0x0003
0x0002       Class2.obj 
0x0003       string      "test"
```

Then we run:

```
class2.obj = class1.obj;
```

So now the memory looks like:

```
Mem Address  Name        Value
0x0001       Class1.obj  0x0003
0x0002       Class2.obj  0x0003
0x0003       string      "test"
```

And finally:

```
class2.obj = "test2";
```

Gives us this:

```
Mem Address  Name        Value
0x0001       Class1.obj  0x0003
0x0002       Class2.obj  0x0004
0x0003       string      "test"
0x0004       string      "test2"
```

Note that `Class1.obj`'s value has not been changed. It's still pointing to the original object.

Comment: How can the pointer for Class1.obj point to the new value for the Class2.obj whenever the Class2.obj is changed?

Comment: @user3736648 The short answer is it's not possible in regular C#. The long answer is, you'd need `Class1` and `Class2` to store the value of the object's memory address (in this case `0x0003`) rather than the string, and manually handle the dereferencing. If you do not have a background in pointers and memory manipulation, and you're interested in it - I'd advise using a lower level language like C or C++ first. Otherwise, there's almost definitely a better way to do what you're trying to achieve. Having `class1` mutable by changing `class2` is a recipe for disaster

Answer (score 0):

```
class2.obj = class1.obj;
```

Here you are assigning value from class1.obj to the class2.obj, not changing its reference. Therefore class1.obj value will not change when class2.obj value changes.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, try using something like :

```
myclass a = new myclass();
a.integer = 1;

myclass b = new myclass();
b.integer = 2;

a = b;
```